# What is the usage of Template Panel in Guidewire PCF? Can I use it to implement the Java script functionality from Guidewire?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

Using Template Panel in PCF, Java script functionality is getting triggered from the guidewire. And the functionality works as expected. But I couldn't find what is the exact definition for Template Panel and using of Template panel to execute Java script is the right way? Current Guidewire Version 8.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the OOTB usages of the Template Panel widget in GW PCF files to understand the usage and context. As you said, it is used to trigger custom JS from PCF, and the most common usage of Template Panel is to embed an iFrame to third-party applications such as Payment Processor. Here is the code snippet that shows the usage of the Template Panel in a PCF.

```
<TemplatePanel>
          <TemplatePanelContents><![CDATA[
                ..............
              ]]>
           </TemplatePanelContents>
</TemplatePanel>
```